# Массив "треугольников"

Tags: javascript

У нас есть массив `A` элементы которой являются натуральными числами. Нужно написать функцию, которая получает массив  `A`  и возвращает массив `B` из трех элементов так, чтобы тремя элементами массива `B` нужно было бы построить треугольник с наибольшей площадью.
Площадь треугольника для сторон `a, b, c` нужно найти следующим образом

```
S = Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)), где p = (a + b + c) / 2
```

Например: 
если дан массив `A = [5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2]` то получим массив `B = [5, 4, 3]`

```
function greatAreaTriangle () {}

console.log(greatAreaTriangle ([5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2]))     // [5, 4, 3]
console.log(greatAreaTriangle ([3, 4, 8, 10, 13]))     // [8, 10, 13]
console.log(greatAreaTriangle ([0, 12, 0, 0, 15, 0, 10, 0]))     // [12, 15, 10]
console.log(greatAreaTriangle ([5, 4, 3, 10, 1, 2]))     // [5, 4, 3]
```

Поможете решить задачу?

Comment: Оппа. Чуть сложнее, чем казалось) Надо еще проверять, может ли из чисел получиться треугольник.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let log = e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e));

log( greatAreaTriangle([100, 51, 50, 49, 48]) );
log( greatAreaTriangle([5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2]) );
log( greatAreaTriangle([3, 4, 8, 10, 13]) );
log( greatAreaTriangle([0, 12, 0, 0, 15, 0, 10, 0]) );
log( greatAreaTriangle([5, 4, 3, 10, 1, 2]) );
log( greatAreaTriangle([1000, 50, 400]) );

/***/

function greatAreaTriangle(arr) {
  let sorted = arr.slice().sort( (a, b) => b - a ); // Сортировка чисел по убыванию
  // slice без аргументов - копирует массив, чтобы сортировка не модифицировала `arr`
  
  let biggestArea = getArea(sorted[0], sorted[1], sorted[2]);
  // Поиск наибольшей площади
  for( let i = 1; i < sorted.length - 2; i++ ){
    let attempt = getArea(sorted[i], sorted[i+1], sorted[i+2]);
    if( biggestArea.area < attempt.area ) biggestArea = attempt;
  }
  
  return biggestArea.area ? getInitOrderedSides(arr, biggestArea) : null;
  // См. "Тернарный оператор"
  
  /****/
  
  function getInitOrderedSides(arr, obj){
    // Из объекта достаются стороны треугольника,
    // и сортируются по индексу в начальном массиве.
    return [obj.a, obj.b, obj.c].sort( (a, b) => arr.indexOf(a) - arr.indexOf(b) );
  }
}

function getArea(a, b, c) {
  let p = (a + b + c) / 2;
  let body = p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c);
  
  return {
    area: body <= 0 ? 0 : Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)),
    a,
    b,
    c,
  };
}
```

Comment: @Igor А так хотелось найти короткий чит) Оказалось легче просто перебрать.

Comment: Я тоже не вижу, как это сделать без вычисления площади. Квадртный корень, конечно, можно не брать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ и если можно еще один вопрос как можно сделать чтобы в место [13,10,8] вывел [8, 10, 13] (исходний массив [3, 4, 8, 10, 13]), а вместо [15,12,10] вывел [12, 15, 10] (исходний массив [0, 12, 0, 0, 15, 0, 10, 0])  то есть как сделать чтобы порядок выводения из исходного массива сохранисля?
Заранее мои извенения и спасибо

Comment: @Dima Добавил функцию, которая дополнительно сортирует финальный массив.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за то что нашли время и помогли. И за коментарии тоже спасибо